# Change value of mysql system variable

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Server version:

```
mysql See 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

For the research that does just change the file /etc/mysql/my.conf and insert the new value, that's what I did.

Then according to a mysql documentation it is said:

> There are several ways to see the names and values ​​of system variables: To see the values ​​and a server based on your compiled defaults and all the option files it reads, use this command: mysqld --verbose - - Help

That returns me:

```
...
ft-min-word-len 2
innodb-ft-min-token-size 2
...
```

Between when I'm doing a direct check in mysql I have the following return:

```
MySQL [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES;

...
ft_min_word_len | 4
...
innodb_ft_min_token_size | 3
```

At first I researched I should change the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf, where it says:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# MariaDB / MySQL tools read configuration files in the following $
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set options only for MariaDB.
# 4. "~ / .my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
Searching for the file containing as a command:
```

me @ me: / $ sudo find / -name "*.cnf" -print

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql-clients.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf
/etc/alternatives/my.cnf
/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
/usr/share/ssl-cert/ssleay.cnf
/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf
```

So I changed the archives:

/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf

```
...
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2
ft_min_word_len = 2
...
```

/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

```
...
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2
ft_min_word_len = 2
...
```

/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

```
...
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2
ft_min_word_len = 2
...
```

When, i cheking in mysql it returns the default values ​​4 and 3 instead of 2 for both.

Is there another way to set these values?

<sub>sorry my bad english</sub>

Comment: And you obviously restarted the mysql server after modifying the .cnf files?

Comment: @dbdemon Tks for atention for each edit i doing : `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`...  :.(..
I cant find my mistake second day in row with this problem... Is a GCP instance i dont  know if change something... I install mysql with security_installation, create a new user...

Comment: ...But i have 1 dubit, what is that file `~/.my.cnf`, becouse with the command: `mysqld --help --verbose`: `Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf ` @dbdemon maybe i need change something in the last file, but i cant find him

Comment: `~/.my.cnf` is optional, and in your home directory. It's only read by clients, so not useful for the problem you're describing here, I think.

Comment: See [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_ft_min_token_size) and [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#ft_min_word_len) for documentation about the two variables. And just a thought, if you go to the Linux shell and list the mysql processes, e.g. `ps -ef | grep mysql`, does that show these variables as part of the mysqld command? If so, I think the values given there will override anything you have in the config files.

Comment: @dbdemon the return of the command is: 
`root      3654     1  0 Feb05 ?        00:00:00 sudo grep -Ril mysqld /
root      3655  3654  0 Feb05 ?        00:00:03 grep -Ril mysqld /
mysql    20537     1  0 15:09 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     20933 20725  0 15:42 pts/1    00:00:00 grep mysql`

Comment: I already leaned on these links, the problem is when i check inside mysql with show variables display the default values.... if i test query with 4 chars is ok, but 2 not... I edit and rebuild fulltext index, restart server and not change...

Comment: Have you tried `grep`ing for `ft_min_word_len` or `ft-min-word-len` (you can use '-' instead of '_' in config files) in the list of .cnf files you found? Maybe it's overriding the values you're trying to set.

Comment: with underline display the files:

root@ssi:/# grep -rnw '/etc' -e 'ft_min_word_len' 
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf:3:ft_min_word_len=2
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:15:ft_min_word_len=2
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql-clients.cnf:8:ft_min_word_len=2
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf:7:ft_min_word_len=2
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf:4:ft_min_word_len=2
/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf:24:ft_min_word_len=2

Without nothing

Comment: Oh man.. hole fukin*** shi****, sorry my words.... GCP sucks... https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags